Why does HighCharts call go to an external server when I'm using offline exporting
I decided to use offline\client side exporting and based on the information shown in Highcharts Client Side exporting it shows that all I need to do is add a link to offline-exporting.js.  I have done this and I get a CORS error saying my attempt to access https://export-svg.highcharts.com is blocked by CORS restriction.  Why is the offline exporting even attempting to go to an outside link?  I thought the idea of offline exporting/client side exporting was that the chart information was not to be passed to an external server and instead served up via my web browser.
For reference I'm using Chrome Version 131.0.6778.205 and HighCharts version 12.1.1.  I'm running the application on my machine (localhost).  I am not using any custom code to call the chart
So I'm wondering why is an offline/client side exporting leaving and trying to access an external server?  How do I go about fixing this as all I see according to the documentation is to just add the offline-exporting.js link after the exporting.js link?
Thanks in advance,
Bob

Can you add a simplified [mre] of your code that reproduces this behavior?

documentation shows an example of loading the script from code.highcharts.com. How and where does  export-svg.highcharts.com  come into the picture?

The documentation shows the 3 script files that should be used as sources.  That's my question/issue, why is it going to export-svg.highcharts.com?  I downloaded all the files associated with HighCharts version 12.1.1 and in the file offline-exporting.src.js the file has a url option set to export-svg.highcharts.com.

When offline-exporting fails to export the chart on the client side, there is a fallback to the public Export Server instance, which can be either disabled or enabled. By default, it is enabled since certain older browsers might experience issues when exporting locally.
You can disable this fallback by setting exporting.fallbackToExportServer to false.
Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.fallbackToExportServer
